# PHP error_reporting E_NOTICE turned off, now gives pop-up warning

Tags: php, database, windows-server-2003, error-reporting, e-notices

I am trying to get rid of lots of Notice errors in our Windows server 2003 database. I already changed the error_reporting to E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE. But every time I set the value to ignore the Notice errors it gives me two pop-ups on the page without any text. I can close these pop-ups and the  database works fine then. It is just so frustrating that I have to close those two pop-ups every time a page loads.
Can anyone tell me how to stop those two pop-ups from showing?

Thanks,
Thomas

Since I don't have enough reputation I can't post images directly, but here's a link to a screenshot: [Screenshot](http://uploadenfoto.nl/pictures/50d39f824193aeca9037a2d6a0fdf8f6.png)

[image]

Comment: PHP doesn't make pop ups.

Comment: If you can't describe or discern yourself where these popups originate (browser or windows service?), a screenshot might be helpful.

Comment: @JohnConde *Ah*, but wouldn't it be nice?

Comment: @Fred-ii- A new way to annoy users!

Comment: @JohnConde Plus, more work for us!

Comment: I've added a screenshot. If PHP can't make pop ups, what is creating the pop ups then when I set error_reporting in the PHP main file to ~E_NOTICE?

Comment: The popup is definitely generated by JavaScript not PHP.

Comment: @Fred-ii- popups when running scripts from CLI would definitely be an "interesting" experience

Comment: @MarkBaker Hahaha, indeed and freak out a few.

Comment: *"If PHP can't make pop ups, what is creating the pop ups..."* - I see "FancyBox" in your screenshot; that uses JS/jQuery, so that seems to be the most likely cause. Disable JS and that popup *should* go away.

Comment: @Thomas You have, *you* put, some Javascript in the page somehow that produces those popups.

Comment: Perhaps a bad AJAX request is kicking off an alert?

Comment: just as an idea - if this is IE might not some activeX/IE-exclusive stuff be also a cuplit creating popups?

Comment: (I didn;'t create the database or the page, so it's a bit hard for me to find everything.)
I edited the main.php and tried to delete every javascript code and test if the pop-ups would go away. Unfortunately they still exist. I don't understand it...